# How can i get value of array using ajax function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

i have json array

[image]

and this is my code

```
 var conf_url = "https://192.168.236.33/confbridge_participants/conference_participants.json?cid=0090000007";

   getParticipant(conf_url, function(output){
        var uid = output.uid;
        document.write(uid);
        });

 function getParticipant(conf_uri, handleData) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: conf_uri,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      jsonpCallback: 'callback',
      contentType: "application/javascript",
      success: function(data) {
        handleData(data);
     //   console.log(data);
      }
    });

  }
```

i want to get uid of each object

but my output is undefined .  . What am i doing wrong ? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have iterate through the object list to output the value. You are getting an object array.

so

```
data.forEach(function(obj){
    console.log(obj['uid'])
})
```

the following would output the uid.

**Update**

You are passing a callback function to the Ajax request. So just do the following way.

```
getParticipant(conf_url, function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(obj){
       document.write(obj['uid'])
    })
});

function getParticipant(conf_uri, handleData) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: conf_uri,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: 'callback',
        contentType: "application/javascript",
        success: handleData(data);
    });
}
```

pass the callback function directly to the ajax success and you can access the data returned from the ajax inside the callback function.

Comment: uhm . . how can i output it on my code `getParticipant(conf_url, function(output){
        var uid = output.uid;
        document.write(uid);
        });`   ?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
 console.log(Object.keys(data).map(function(value, index){ return data[value].uid; }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop to read the uid of each object. Your code now is reading the uid attribute on the Array object, that's why you are getting an undefined

Answer (score 1):

```
var response = JSON.parse(data);
response.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item.uid);
});
```

Comment: uhm . . how can i output it on my code `getParticipant(conf_url, function(output){ var uid = output.uid; document.write(uid); });` ?

Comment: @biancamihai : actually you don't need to parse data to json since it already comes as json. the data type is set to json in the ajax request.